# Doctrine 2 - Entidades em mais de um diretório

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-2

Bom dia pessoal, estou iniciando em Doctrine 2.4 e estou desenvolvendo um sistema onde separo arquivos do core de arquivos da aplicação, da seguinte forma:

```
/root
   |-- /src
        |-- /App
              |-- /Model
                    |-- **(Entidades da Aplicação)**
        |-- /Core
              |-- /Model
                    |-- **(Entidades do Core)**
```

Na documentação do Doctrine mostra a seguinte forma de setar 1 diretório para as Entitys:

```
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode);
```

Mas como configurar quando tenho **mais de 1 diretório** que conterá as Entitys da minha aplicação, como meu exemplo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples:

Coloque assim:

```
$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src/App/Model/", __DIR__."/src/Core/Model/"), $isDevMode);
```

Como o primeiro paramentro de `createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration` é do tipo `array`, então, coloque os diretórios que fazem parte do mapeamento de sua aplicação, vejo o exemplo do paramentro logo abaixo:

```
array(__DIR__."/src/App/Model/", __DIR__."/src/Core/Model/")
```

*Referências:*

- [Object Relational Mapper](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html)
- [Code for the ORM Tutorial](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2-orm-tutorial)

Comment: Poxa cara, é assim tão difícil (kkkk)!!! putz. Muito Obrigado, assim que chegar em casa testarei, e assim darei um feedback!

Comment: Harry Potter, testei o código e funcionou. Muito obrigado!